# Adding Encryption options to GeoServer SQL Server connection

Tags: geoserver, sql, encryption

I have set up an HTTPS connection between GeoServer and an Azure database using the SQL Server extension, however I would like to add encryption options to the connection string.  Is this possible in GeoServer 2.16 (currently running on Tomcat 9)?  Would I have to modify the actual extension itself?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would need to modify [`SQLServerDataStoreFactory`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-sqlserver/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/sqlserver/SQLServerDataStoreFactory.java) to have some extra parameters (as documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-2017)). Then modify [`getJDBCUrl`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-sqlserver/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/sqlserver/SQLServerDataStoreFactory.java#L149) to add those parameters to the generated URL, [the `INTSEC` parameter shows how](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-sqlserver/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/sqlserver/SQLServerDataStoreFactory.java#L166) this is done.

Comment: disclaimer: I have never used java before.  I decompiled the extension (jar), added the necessary parameters, and am trying to recompile the java into a class.  This is what I'm running: `javac -cp ".;dir\geoserver.war;dir\gt-jdbc-sqlserver-22.0.jar" "dir\SQLServerDataStoreFactory.java"` (dir is the directory the files are in).  However, I'm getting errors that packages don't exist (like org.geotools.jdbc).  Where would I get these packages?

Comment: please see https://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/docs/index.html for how to compile a GeoTools jar -